# Frage über die Verwendung des Genitivs und die Auslassung eines Personalpronomens bei einem Zitat

Tags: genitive, personal-pronoun

Welche Rolle spielt "ihrer" im folgenden Zitat? D.h., woher kommt hier der Genitiv? Und wieso kann "ich" nach "Wirklichkeit" wegfallen?

> Manche Dinge in meiner Umgebung sind mir nicht ganz geheuer. Sei es, weil ich mich ihrer zu bedienen scheine, aber in Wirklicheit weiß, daß ich sie bediene?
> <sub>[Vilém Flusser (1920-1991): *Dinge und Undinge (1993)*]</sub>

Comment: Ich bin mir ziemlich sicher, dass in deinem Zitat ein "mich" fehlt.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Es heißt *sich einer Sache bedienen* mit Genitivobjekt.

> Er bedient sich dabei eines Hilfsmittels.

---

Das *ich* im *aber*-Teilsatz kann nicht nur wegfallen, es muss sogar zwingend ausgelassen werden, denn es handelt sich um alternative Enden des ersten Nebensatzes:

> Sei es, weil ich **(mich) ihrer zu bedienen scheine.**
>
> Sei es, weil ich **aber in Wirklichkeit weiß, dass ich sie bediene.**

Das *ich* ist am Anfang dieses Nebensatzes ja schon enthalten.

Answer (score 0):

Frage: Welche Rolle spielt »ihrer« in folgendem Zitat? D.h., woher kommt hier der Genitiv?

Antwort:
Das Verb *»bedienen«* wird hier in der Bedeutung *»sich einer Sache bedienen«* verwendet. Das Verb benötigt bei dieser Konstruktion zwei Objekte:

- Die Person, die die Aktion ausführt und gleichzeitig Nutznießer der Aktion ist: reflexives Akkusativobjekt (ein Reflexivpronomen im Akkusativ)
- Die Sache, die verwendet wird, und die dem Benutzer einen Vorteil bringt: Genitivobjekt.

In Flussers Zitat ist die verwendete Sache *»die Dinge in meiner Umgebung«,* die im vorangegangenen Satz erwähnt wurden und somit Teil des Kontext sind. Weil diese Dinge bereits im Kontext existieren, muss man sie kurz darauf nicht noch einmal explizit erwähnen, sondern kann mit einem Personalpronomen darauf verweisen. Nachdem die referenzierten Dinge in der Mehrzahl stehen, muss das Personalpronomen eine Pluralform sein, und weil es als Genitivobjekt des Verbs *»bedienen«* verwendet wird, muss es im Genitiv stehen. Daher muss es *»ihrer«* sein.

Verben, die ein Gentivobjekt verlangen, sind eher selten in der deutschen Sprache, und die meisten von ihnen sind veraltend oder bereits veraltet. Auf Wiktionary gibt es [eine Liste dieser Verben](https://de.wiktionary.org/wiki/Verzeichnis:Deutsch/Verben_mit_Genitiv).

---

Frage: Und wieso kann »ich« nach »Wirklichkeit« wegfallen?

Antwort:
Nach *»Wirklichkeit«* wäre *»ich«* am falschen Platz, aber davor dürfte es stehen:

> Manche Dinge in meiner Umgebung sind mir nicht ganz geheuer. Sei es, weil ich mich ihrer zu bedienen scheine, aber [ich] in Wirklichkeit weiß, dass ich sie bediene?

Auch das wäre möglich:

> Manche Dinge in meiner Umgebung sind mir nicht ganz geheuer. Sei es, weil ich mich ihrer zu bedienen scheine, [ich] aber in Wirklichkeit weiß, dass ich sie bediene?

<sup>Die Gründe für diese Reihenfolge zu diskutieren, würde den Rahmen dieser Antwort sprengen. Die Positionierung von *»aber«* wurde hier auf german.stackexchange schon in anderen Fragen thematisiert.</sup>

Hier wurden zwei Sätze zu einem verschmolzen. Um die Analyse ein wenig zu vereinfachen, mache aus der Frage eine Aussage (Sei es? → Es sei.) und gleichzeitig wandle ich den Konjunktiv I in einen Indikativ um (*sei → ist*). Dadurch wird es nämlich einfacher, die beiden einzelnen Sätze tatsächlich getrennt voneinander zu halten:

> Es ist, weil ich mich ihrer zu bedienen scheine.
> Es ist, weil ich in Wirklichkeit weiß, dass ich sie bediene.

In beiden Sätzen ist das, was nach dem ersten Komma steht, ein Konditionalsatz, also ein untergeordneter Nebensatz, der eine Begründung für die Aussage des Hauptsatzes liefert (Hauptsatz in beiden Fällen: *»Es ist.«*) Diese beiden Konditionalsätze kann man hintereinander an denselben Hauptsatz anfügen, dazu muss man sie nur mit einer Konjunktion (*und, oder, aber, ...*) verbinden. Weil Fusser die beiden Ursachen als Gegensatz darstellen möchte, hat er sich für *»aber«* entschieden:

> Es ist, weil ich mich ihrer zu bedienen scheine, aber weil ich in Wirklichkeit weiß, dass ich sie bediene.

Jetzt kommen in diesem Satz aber die Subjunktion *»weil«* und das Subjekt *»ich«* doppelt vor, ähnlich wie in diesem Satz:

> Heinrich ist müde, weil er den ganzen Tag gearbeitet hat, und weil er schon früh aufgestanden ist.

In solchen Fällen kann man die Wiederholungen einfach weglassen. Man nennt das eine [Koordinationsellipse](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Koordinationsellipse):

> 1. Heinrich ist müde, weil er den ganzen Tag gearbeitet hat, und schon früh aufgestanden ist.
> 2. Es ist, weil ich mich ihrer zu bedienen scheine, aber in Wirklichkeit weiß, dass ich sie bediene.

---

Nachdem nun klar sein sollte, wie der Satz 2 zu verstehen ist, schließe ich den Kreis, indem ich ihn schrittweise wieder zurück in den Satz verwandle, den Flusser geschrieben hat:

Zuerst mache ich aus der Aussage eine Frage:

> Ist es, weil ich mich ihrer zu bedienen scheine, aber in Wirklichkeit weiß, dass ich sie bediene?

Dann wandle ich den Indikativ in den Konjunktiv I um:

> Sei es, weil ich mich ihrer zu bedienen scheine, aber in Wirklichkeit weiß, dass ich sie bediene?

Der Konjunktiv ist in Wahrheit nicht notwendig. Er wird hier als Stilmittel verwendet.

Das Werk wurde vor 1996 publiziert, daher wurde darin die alte Rechtschreibung verwendet (*dass → daß*):

> Sei es, weil ich mich ihrer zu bedienen scheine, aber in Wirklichkeit weiß, daß ich sie bediene?